# Left rotate BigInteger?

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, biginteger, bit-shift

Is there a way to properly left rotate (not just shift) BigIntegers of a fixed size?

I tried writing a method which resembles the classic rotation method which is used to rotate integers, but it does not work on BigIntegers. It just shifts the bits to the left by r positions, filling zeros at the end.

```
public static BigInteger rotate(BigInteger n, int r){
        return n.shiftLeft(r).or(n.shiftRight(128-r));
    }
```

EDIT: Not using BigIntegers and using arrays of longs or integers looks like another option, but I'm not sure how you'd be able to combine them (except using BigIntegers) to perform the rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually not so easy. Where would the rotation point be? That is easy for fixed size numbers like 32 bit or 64 bit integers, but not for BigIntegers.

But... in theory, BigIntegers are unlimited in size, and two's complement (or at least, they behave like they are, in reality they are usually sign-magnitude). So positive numbers are (virtually) preceded with an unlimited number of 0 bits and negative numbers with an unlimited number of 1 bits.

So rotating left by 1 would actually mean that you shift left by 1, and if the number was/is negative, the lowest bit is set to 1.

### UPDATE

If the BigInteger is just used to represent a **fixed size** integer (BigIntegers themselves do not have a fixed size), you will have to move the top bits to the bottom. Then you can do something like:

```
public static BigInteger rotateLeft(BigInteger value, int shift, int bitSize)
{
    // Note: shift must be positive, if necessary add checks.

    BigInteger topBits = value.shiftRight(bitSize - shift);
    BigInteger mask = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(bitSize).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
    return value.shiftLeft(shift).or(topBits).and(mask);
}
```

And you call it like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    BigInteger rotated = rotateLeft(new 
        BigInteger("1110000100100011010001010110011110001001101010111100110111101111" + 
                   "1111111011011100101110101001100001110110010101000011001000010010",
            2), 7, 128);
    System.out.println(rotated.toString(2));
}
```

*Note: I did test this and it seems to produce the desired result:*

```
10010001101000101011001111000100110101011110011011110111111111110110111001011101010011000011101100101010000110010000100101110000
```

If the bitSize is fixed (e.g. always 128), you can pre-calculate the mask and do not have to pass the bitSize to the function, of course.

#### *EDIT:*

To obtain the mask, instead of shifting `BigInteger.ONE` left, you can just as well do:

```
BigInteger.ZERO.setBit(bitSize).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
```

That is probably a little faster.

Comment: It indeed is really really tricky. BigIntegers are really hard to deal with, at least on this manner. I've been doing some testing on your method, I added a for loop on it to perform the rotation r times (or rotate r bits). But I do not think I am getting the desired result. Here are for example some cases when I rotated a 128-bit number (numbers in binary):

 100001001000110100010101100111100010011010101111001101111011111111111011011100101110101001100001110110010101000011001000010010 - original

Comment: 1000010010001101000101011001111000100110101011110011011110111111111110110111001011101010011000011101100101010000110010000100100 - r=1;
       100001001000110100010101100111100010011010101111001101111011111111111011011100101110101001100001110110010101000011001000 - r=2;

       100001001000110100010101100111100010011010101111001101111111111111110110111001011101010011000011101100101010000110010000 - r=3;

Comment: Looks indeed interesting. The BigInteger I am supposed to rotate is of a fixed size always, so I'll modify the code in the way you suggested.
Now the note you left, "n must be positive", I am not sure what n represents here. Does it imply that the BigInteger has to be positive?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `shift`. Will edit that. In Java, BigIntegers will shift *right* if the shift passed to `shiftLeft` is negative. I think that makes no sense (a shift left function should always shift left, never right, IMO), but that is how it is in Java.

Comment: If that's it then thank you sir. I can work with this.

Comment: Constructing overly large BigIntegers is expensive.  So if you mask before the shift left instead of after it, then you will use a smaller BigInteger mask, and it will be faster.  So to fix: `BigInteger mask = BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(bitSize - shift).subtract(BigInteger.ONE);` and `return value.and(mask).shiftLeft(shift).or(topBits);`